# Can USB 3.0 device without its own power be plugged in to USB 2.0 port without blowing it out?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I have a computer with three USB 2.0 ports, but only one of them works correctly (the other two disconnect on their own after a seemingly random interval; it's a refurbished Lenovo ThinkPad running Windows 10). I successfully plugged in a hard drive enclosure that uses USB 3.0. It plugs in to AC power. It works better than I thought it would.

I also bought a 2TB USB 3.0 external hard drive. It's much smaller than the hard drive in the enclosure and it's got four times the capacity. But it doesn't have its own power.

Twenty years ago, I worked in a computer lab. A guy plugged in a 1GB thumb drive into an USB port and blew it out. We were told to post signs telling people not to use thumb drives in excess of 512MB. This is the only reason I'm worried that a 2TB USB 3.0 external hard drive without its own power plugged into a USB 2.0 port might be a problem.

I've been shopping for a brand new computer with all USB 3.0 ports. In the meantime, would it be safe to plug in the external hard drive or would that risk disabling my only working USB port for the time being?

Comment: In my experience overcurrent shutdowns only last until you shut down the machine.  They're supposed to be protected by polyfuses (which are resettable, more like a circuit breaker.)  That being said, don't expect a self-powered USB 3 drive to work on a USB 2 port--a spinning drive needs more power than a USB 2 port can deliver.  Such drives normally come with a special USB cable that plugs into two ports.

Comment: @harrymc Almost, not quite. I thought about offering a bounty on that question with an update criterion, but that option's closed off to me for the time being.

Comment: I wasn't the only one. You could still edit your post, explain why it's not a duplicate and ask for it to be reopened.

Comment: @harrymc No, that's fine, the differences between these two questions boil down to a bunch of "it depends." Besides, in my particular case, the hard drive enclosure already contains the vast majority of the files I want to put on the new computer. For anything else I can use smaller media.